# Why won't my svg animation work?

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have this svg that I've been trying to animate for like two weeks now ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg1"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="49.595489 30.040314 84.135223 84.305336"
   height="84.305336mm"
   width="84.135223mm">


    <defs>
        <style>
            .logo{
                stroke-dasharray: 800;
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                -webkit-animation: dash 2s linear forwards;         
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes dash {
                from {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 800;
                }
                to {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </defs>

  <path class="logo"
     id="logo"
     d="m 70.303571,78.340773 c -4.032971,0.006 -8.033187,1.698025 -10.862132,4.572387 -2.828946,2.874362 -4.455685,6.891674 -4.445904,10.924637 0.0095,3.927963 1.572604,7.841853 4.315065,10.653953 2.74246,2.8121 6.641232,4.47709 10.569138,4.45364 4.633366,-0.0277 9.108311,-2.43049 12.384652,-5.70683 3.574526,-3.57453 6.411017,-6.242046 9.347584,-9.825986 0,0 7.17598,-6.918764 10.743336,-10.51178 3.56737,-3.593016 7.41006,-7.169152 11.08478,-10.843875 3.34645,-3.346446 6.32139,-6.581106 9.51049,-9.812482 3.3753,-3.420038 5.15813,-7.12199 5.18334,-11.661986 0.0216,-3.889398 -1.60848,-8.155743 -4.38434,-10.880165 -2.77587,-2.724421 -6.6563,-4.279784 -10.54572,-4.261811 -3.8759,0.01791 -7.72562,1.595418 -10.48769,4.314587 -2.762056,2.71917 -5.002206,6.149863 -4.776456,11.428746 -0.0484,4.514439 2.874106,9.098792 5.148056,11.372746 3.19237,3.192372 6.9848,6.227335 10.17717,9.419709 3.20164,3.201638 6.0452,5.990107 9.58187,9.526778 1.80732,1.807321 3.93629,5.149881 4.68721,7.593023 0.75092,2.443141 1.01197,5.054051 0.5999,7.576553 -0.55185,3.378163 -2.33545,6.072793 -4.93781,8.296363 -2.60235,2.22358 -5.80201,3.69214 -9.22483,3.7206 -4.69281,0.039 -9.04011,-1.51725 -12.0905,-4.81311 -3.187696,-3.44421 -7.211206,-7.037566 -10.268806,-10.463896 -3.057595,-3.42633 -6.28628,-6.607684 -9.408672,-9.762441 -3.174881,-3.207791 -7.386446,-5.316042 -11.899731,-5.30936 z"

     style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#febc00;stroke-width:10.80000019;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" />

</svg>
```

I followed instructions in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBdbgD2BaEI). Even tried adding an extra `style` line like he did in the video by copy pasting `style` from inside `path`. I'm not sure it makes a difference where those attributes are.

```
<style type = "txt/css">
        .logo{fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#febc00;stroke-width:10.80000019;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1}
```

but it didn't work :( If i leave the line above and remove `style` from `path`, all the attributes get lost, so I guess it can't reference them the way he does in the video. I'm not sure what's wrong this time.

the html source code is just

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equip="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

              <title> SVG Line Animation Demo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style = "text-align: center; padding: 150px 0;">
            <object>
                <embed src="path.svg">
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try with plain old @keyframes instead of @-webkit-keyframes? The webkit version will not work in all browsers

Comment: @DavidPartyka, i'm using Chrome, i think webkits is Chrome-specific. But yes, I checked, just in case, keyframes doesn't work either in Chrome or IE.

Comment: Change stroke-dashoffset in .logo class to 800, then remove "from" from inside the @keyframes rule

Comment: Does anything happen if you bring all the svg code into your template?

Comment: @DavidPartyka still nothing :<

Comment: @git-e-up, i'm not sure what the proper way of doing that is. I copy pasted all the code and put it inside the <object> tags instead of `embed`, that didn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stroke-dasharray:none that you have set on the path overrides and prevents the animation. Removing that fixes it.

I've also removed the webkit bits so it should work on more browsers now.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg1" version="1.1" viewBox="49.595489 30.040314 84.135223 84.305336" height="84.305336mm" width="84.135223mm">
     
     
     <defs>
      <style>
       .logo{
        stroke-dasharray: 800;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        animation: dash 2s linear forwards;   
       }
       
       @keyframes dash {
        from {
         stroke-dashoffset: 800;
        }
        to {
         stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
       }
      </style>
     </defs>
     
      <path class="logo"
         id="logo"
         d="m 70.303571,78.340773 c -4.032971,0.006 -8.033187,1.698025 -10.862132,4.572387 -2.828946,2.874362 -4.455685,6.891674 -4.445904,10.924637 0.0095,3.927963 1.572604,7.841853 4.315065,10.653953 2.74246,2.8121 6.641232,4.47709 10.569138,4.45364 4.633366,-0.0277 9.108311,-2.43049 12.384652,-5.70683 3.574526,-3.57453 6.411017,-6.242046 9.347584,-9.825986 0,0 7.17598,-6.918764 10.743336,-10.51178 3.56737,-3.593016 7.41006,-7.169152 11.08478,-10.843875 3.34645,-3.346446 6.32139,-6.581106 9.51049,-9.812482 3.3753,-3.420038 5.15813,-7.12199 5.18334,-11.661986 0.0216,-3.889398 -1.60848,-8.155743 -4.38434,-10.880165 -2.77587,-2.724421 -6.6563,-4.279784 -10.54572,-4.261811 -3.8759,0.01791 -7.72562,1.595418 -10.48769,4.314587 -2.762056,2.71917 -5.002206,6.149863 -4.776456,11.428746 -0.0484,4.514439 2.874106,9.098792 5.148056,11.372746 3.19237,3.192372 6.9848,6.227335 10.17717,9.419709 3.20164,3.201638 6.0452,5.990107 9.58187,9.526778 1.80732,1.807321 3.93629,5.149881 4.68721,7.593023 0.75092,2.443141 1.01197,5.054051 0.5999,7.576553 -0.55185,3.378163 -2.33545,6.072793 -4.93781,8.296363 -2.60235,2.22358 -5.80201,3.69214 -9.22483,3.7206 -4.69281,0.039 -9.04011,-1.51725 -12.0905,-4.81311 -3.187696,-3.44421 -7.211206,-7.037566 -10.268806,-10.463896 -3.057595,-3.42633 -6.28628,-6.607684 -9.408672,-9.762441 -3.174881,-3.207791 -7.386446,-5.316042 -11.899731,-5.30936 z"
      
         style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#febc00;stroke-width:10.80000019;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" />
    
    </svg>
```

Comment: !!!!!!!!!! OMGTHANKYOU !!!!!!!!!! you have no idea how many things I've tried and none and of them worked T.T ... You're a genius T.T ... So whenever I want to animate some part of svg I have to make sure it's not a part of `style` already so it doesn't get overwritten?

Comment: you just need to consider CSS specificity so you're not overriding your animation with something more specific.